# When an "improved" edit is approved, change the message to other contending reviewers

Tags: feature-request, review, suggested-edits

I was looking at a suggested edit review [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2546319), and decided to decline it rather than improving it (as it didn't seem like it was worth improving, although there certainly were other things wrong with the original post).  However, another user improved it, which is fine.  However, the message I received was that it was `Approved`.

That confused me, so I had to look to see what happened, and in fact it was `Improved`, not `Approved`.  I understand that `Improved` implies `Approved` in some sense, but it's clearly confusing to a reviewer to see an obviously harmful edit (taking "Hello Friends", which really should be deleted anyway, and making it "hello frnds", for example) approved.

Can we change the `Approved` to `Approved with edits` or `Rejected with edits` in the after-edit-review-completed page, so it's not as confusing to the reviewer (which one depending on the status of the `helpful` checkbox).

Comment: There is a checkbox on the "Improving" page that says "Suggested edit was helpful." As long as that box is checked, the edit really was approved. Should your suggestion apply only to improvements in which the improver unchecked that box?

Comment: @GeorgeCummins Hmm.  I guess so, as long as people behave themselves with that checkbox; I'm not sure if that improvement did or not.  Since I tend to default to trusting people, yes, though I wouldn't mind knowing it was improved anyway (since the checkbox is checked by default).

Comment: What about instead showing "Improved (Approved/Rejected)", to show both the fact that the reviewer used the Improve button, and the status of the original suggested edit? Or, conversely, "Approved/Rejected (Improved)".

Comment: Modified to the suggestion of @EsotericScreenName as I think that makes the most sense.